# Is there a way for slect some columns which rows value is expected

Tags: python, pandas

I am handling a df, and want to select the columns that meet the conditions by filtering the values of a row.

I only know one stupid way：query a cell value in a loop, then get my expect
columns.

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'A':list('abcd'),'B':list('1bfe'),'C':list('ghgk')})
>>> df
   A  B  C
0  a  1  g
1  b  b  h
2  c  f  g
3  d  e  k
>>> #get columns ,condition: second row  equal 'b'
... 
>>> cols = list()
>>> for val in df:
...     if df.loc[1,val] == 'b':
...             cols.append(val)
... 
>>> cols
['A', 'B']
```

Answer (score 1):

use

```
df.columns[df.loc[1]=='b']
```

Comment: df.columns[df.loc[1]=='b'].tolist()

Answer (score 0):

There is this nice way to make queries in pandas dataframes.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':list('abcd'),'B':list('1bfe'),'C':list('ghgk')})
df.query("A == 'a' and B == '1'")
```

This query will return the first row of the dataframe based on the fact that column `A` matches `a` and column `B` matches `1`

Answer (score 0):

On the phone, can’t test but this would run:

```
df.columns[df.loc[1].eq('b')]
```